# How to weld a copper flange with a Nickel alloy pipe?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, welding, welds

I have a copper flange and I want to weld it to a nickel alloy pipe.

Normally, which welding technique is used to join these two parts?

Also what is the filler material to be used to weld a copper part with a nickel alloy part?

Comment: Sounds like brazing will be the technique required.

Comment: What do you mean by nickel alloy? Monel, cupronickel? As commented, sounds more like a job for brazing.

Comment: I think a materials engineer would be using nickel aluminum bronze or aluminum bronze for the flange depending on the fluid and the type of nickel alloy.

Comment: I agree with Mike that brazing is the way to go. I think it's possible with some exotic flux.

Comment: Is this going to be helium tight?

Comment: It si a Nickel Chromium Molyblendum alloy. It has to be welded to a copper flange. 
If brazing is the way to go, what would be the filler material to be used? 

It is a High temperature zone (temp will go upto 1100°C), I am modelling it in Ansys. Hence I need the actual filler material for the simulation.